# What is the difference between Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5 and Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I was wondering which is the difference between `Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5` and `Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15`?

In the [documentation](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/signature/signature.html) they use this function `Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15` but sometimes I've seen that `Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5` was used.

What is the difference and which is better to use?

Comment: _PyCryptodome_ supports [`Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html#pkcs-1-v1-5-rsa) and [`Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_SigScheme-class.html). However, `pkcs1_15` should be used. `PKCS1_v1_5` is only available for backwards compatibility with the **legacy** _PyCrypto_. `pkcs1_15` generates a `ValueError` in case of a failed verification. `PKCS1_v1_5` returns the result of the verification as `True`/`False`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html) is PyCryptodome's implementation of the [*RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2) signature scheme. [`Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html) is the corresponding implementation of the legacy PyCrypto, the PyCryptodome predecessor. PyCryptodome also supports `Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5`, but **solely** for backwards compatibility, i.e. new implementations should use `Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15`.

Note that both libraries differ in processing, e.g. [`Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15.PKCS115_SigScheme#verify()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html#Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15.PKCS115_SigScheme.verify) raises a `ValueError` exception in case of a failed verification, while [`Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_SigScheme#verify()`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_SigScheme-class.html) returns the result of a verification as `True`/`False`.